# Updates to Entities not visible in App Engine Datastore

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I have come across the problem when I update one of my Entities manually in Datastore Viewer in App Engine Console, I cannot see the updates instantly from my Android application that uses that data I have updated. I know that there is Memcache from which the data is retrieved.
Therefore my question is can delete the memchache for the entity I update so my application gets the new data to display? If so can someone tell me how to do it please?

P.S. I have tried using 'Flush Memcache' via the Admin Console and it did not help. I am still getting the 'old' entity

That is how I retrieve my entities. I use JDO for persisting and querying data. In my Data Accessor Object I have got this method which returns all the jobs and converts it to a JSONArray. Eventually this JSONArray is being passed to my mobile application with unfortunately 'old' data.

```
public JSONArray getAll() {

    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

    try {
        Query q = pm.newQuery(Job.class);       
        List<Job> resultSet = (List<Job>) q.execute();
        Collections.sort(resultSet);
        Iterator i =resultSet.iterator();

        while (i.hasNext()){
            Job j = (Job) i.next();

            if(j.getDateDue().after(new Date())){
                JSONObject tempjson;
                tempjson = j.toJSONObject();
                array.put(tempjson);
            }
        }
        return array;
    } 
    catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
    }
```

And this is my Job class. I have trimmed the code for it to show only the attributes and not to take much space.

```
  @PersistenceCapable
  public class Job implements Comparable<Job>{

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Key jobId;
@Persistent
private String jobTitle;
@Persistent
private String jobDescription;
@Persistent
private String address;
@Persistent
private String priority;
@Persistent
private double latitude;
@Persistent
private double longitude;
@Persistent
private String employeeId;
@Persistent
private Date dateAdded;
@Persistent
private Date dateDue;
@Persistent
private boolean completed;
```

It is very important to me that the app works on new updated data straight away. I appreciate any help

Comment: You haven't said how you are retrieving entities.  If it is based on a query and it isn't an ancestor query, you will run into eventual consistancy which can mean you won't see updates immediately.

Comment: Thanks for reply Tim, I have updated my post. You can see now how I query for data.

Comment: As I said earlier you are not using an ancestor query, therefore you will potentially end up with old data due to eventual consistancy.  You should read up on this topic as it's fundamental to understanding how best to use appengine and avoid the problem you are having.

Answer (score 1):

Since you using 'flush memcache', you side-stepped the usual problem of reaching around memcache to update entities when the software you've deployed uses memcache as a cache. The  suspect now is the effect of eventual consistency when writes (puts) and subsequent queries don't use an ancestor (parent) entity. You'll need to show us some code to be sure.

Comment: Hi Dave, I added the code to show how I retrieve the data. I use JDO and I do not think its the right way to achieve what I am after.

Comment: I've not used JDO myself, preferring instead to code directly to the Datastore API. I note that you're not using ancestors, which'll run you afoul of eventual consistency.
 
Not relevant to the problem at hand, but querying for all Jobs, and then sorting the result and filtering based on the current date/time after retrieving them is missing the opportunity to do both the sort and the filter on the server side.